# Powershell splitting variable into multiple

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to pass variables from my batch file to Powershell to post to a database, and everything is working, except if a variable is a string with spaces, Powershell is splitting it up into multiple variables.

Here is my batch file's code:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file C:\TEMP\api.ps1 %CustomerCode% %OrderNumber% %CompanyName%
```

And here is my Powershell code:

```
param($customerCode, $orderNumber, [string]$CompanyName)
Write-Output $CompanyName
```

When `$CompanyName` should equal `Test Company`, Powershell will output `Test`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try quotes?

Comment: How would I do that if I'm setting the variable from a node in XML like this?

`for /f "tokens=2delims=<>    " %%i in ('type *.xml ^|find "CompanyName"') do set "CompanyName=%%i"`

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. You use quotes when passing the argument to the executable.  Every console program that I have ever used in my lifetime you always use quotes to protect the spaces.

Comment: Why don't you use Powershell to natively read the XML file instead of hacking it with batch.

Answer (score 0):

To safely pass environment-variable references from `cmd.exe` (from the command line or a batch file) as command-line arguments, enclose them in `"..."` as follows (parameters `-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` omitted for brevity):

```
powershell -file "C:\TEMP\api.ps1" "%CustomerCode%" "%OrderNumber%" "%CompanyName%"
```

Without `"` as a delimiter, PowerShell would have no way of distinguishing a single parameter with embedded whitespace from multiple whitespace-separated parameters, and value `Test Company` would be interpreted as *2* arguments, `Test` (bound to `$CompanyName` in your case) and `Company` (unbound by your script).